# Reversing a singly linked, sentinel based, list recursively (works, but not in the way I'd like it to)

Tags: java

I'm preparing for interviews and wrote up this simple function for recursively reversing a singly linked list.  The first node is a sentinel node, `head`. The following code works fine for: `list.reverse(list.head.next)`, but I can't seem to get it to work if I just pass it `head`.

```
public Node<T> reverse(Node<T> current)
{
    if (current == null)
        return head;

    if (current.next == null)
    {
        head.next = current;
        return current;
    }

    reverse(current.next).next = current;
    current.next = null;
    return current;
}
```

I assume it doesn't work when I pass it `head` instead of `head.next` because I say `current.next = null`, but even if I check if `current == head` or if `current.data == null` and only use `current.next = null` when those aren't true, it still doesn't work.  I'm sure there's a really simple fix, but I'm just not seeing it right now.

The above if passed `head` returns an empty list, and if the suggested changes are made, simply doesn't finish running, but I don't get any sort of error.

Comment: what is "head"? are you having an empty node as "head node"?  Why you are calling `list.reverse(list.head.next)`?  Isn't your linked list being just a reference to the head node?  If you have a list container wrapping that, why do you need to pass the head node manually? shouldn't it looks like `list.reverse()` ?

Comment: FTR, this is not homework and I know how to do this iteratively and recursively in a different manner.  Nonetheless, I feel that my code above, without adding additional parameters, should be able to work.

Comment: still I believe my question is still valid no matter it is recursive or iterative...

Comment: The first node is a sentinel node, ie it doesn't have anything in it.  The first actual node with content is at `head.next`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(EDITED)
I kind of get your problem now:

Simply speaking, the sentinel head acts simply as a pointer to the first node, instead of being part of the linked list.  Therefore it will not be involved in the reverse process, and need to handle separately.

which means, the original list looks like:

```
HEAD -> a -> b -> c -> null
```

after reverse, it should look like

```
HEAD -> c -> b -> a -> null
```

In brief, it should look like (assume your code already works when passing in head.next)

```
public Node<T> reverse(Node<T> current)
{
    if (current == head) {
        return reverse(current.next);
    }

    // rest of your original code.
}
```

---

Just a further suggestion:

Your reverse() method, as an public instance method of your list class, shouldn't accept the current node, as it is conceptually meaningless for caller.

I believe you should make this method protected, which means something like:

```
public void reverse() {
    this.head = reverseInternal(head);
}

private Node<T> reverseInternal(Node<T> node) {
    // your original reverse logic
}
```

With such encapsulation, you don't even need to struggle before how to make your reverse works when you pass in the sentinel head: you can simply call `reverseInternal(head.next)` in your public `reverse()` method.

Comment: I know how to do this iteratively.  I want to know how to make it so my code as stated will work.

Comment: oops, do you need that to be recursive? Then probably the other answer is what you should look into

Comment: I edited your code and now it works.  Thanks.  I was hoping for a different solution, but I can't argue with the results.

Answer (score 1):

First: if it returns an empty list it doesn't "work".

There is no need for head to be an empty node. You should normally just keep the first node (in your case `list.head.next`) as your `list.head`. `head` should be a reference to where the list starts, not a separate node.

The reason your code empties the list when you pass it `list.head` is it sets `list.head.next` to null. This is because you assume the node you pass to the list is a regular one, while your head node is special.

Here's a solution for your assumptions (I'll assume someone insisted on this bizarre detached head thing. Just don't do it if you're designing the list yourself. Please...)

```
public Node<T> reverse(Node<T> current)
{
    if (current == null)
        return head;

    if (current.next == null)
    {
        head.next = current;
        return current;
    }
    Node<T> temp = current.next;
    current.next = null;
    head.next = temp;
    reverse(temp).next = current;
    return current;
}
```

Explanation: This still sets the last node's next to `null`, but it pushes the list's head one spot down as it runs through the list, eventually pointing it to the last (now first) member.

Comment: The sentinel approach actually makes a lot of sense, especially in a doubly linked list.  It removes all edge cases and allows you to write one base function for all adds and removes, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This reeks of homework.

But still.

In general:

```
f(Node<T> current, ...) {

     f(current.next, ...);

}
```

For a list `a > b > c > d > e` sitting in the midle at `d`, one
probably has built `c > b > a` already, so guess what is needed as additional parameter to `f`?

Good luck.

---

***After comments:***

```
public Node<T> reverse(Node<T> current)
{
    return reverseRec(current, null);
}

/**
 * @param current to-do (sub-)list.
 * @param resultDone done reversed list sofar.
 * @return reversed result.
 */
public Node<T> reverseRecursively(Node<T> current, Node<T> resultDone)
{
    if (current == null) {
        return resultDone;
    }
    Node<T> next = current.next;
    current.next = resultDone;
    return reverseRecursively(next, current);
}
```

Comment: It's not homework, and one should be able to do this with only one parameter, no?

Comment: no, unless you group several parameter into one parameter object :P

Comment: So it works perfectly if I pass it the list the node starting at the first actual element, but if I want to pass the sentinel node, I have to completely modify the function.  That just doesn't sound correct.  Not saying you're wrong, but at the moment, that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sometimes recursion with an in-parameter and result work. Here you need two parameters: for the work to do (`d > e`), and the work done (`c > b > a`) as `reversed` gives no access to its last element. Using an extra `concat` or so would do too.